# Railstutorial (Michael Hartl) Chatper 10 Exercise 2: Pagination Breaks Feed Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I used the following to write tests for chapter 10 exercises 1 and 2 in the static_pages_spec.rb and when I got those other tests to pass, I got the following error:

```
  1) Static pages Home page for signed-in users should render the user's feed
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector("li##{item.id}", text: item.content)
       expected css "li#1138" with text "Lorem ipsum" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:25:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Apparently the line item.id test broke somehow as soon as FactoryGirl creates more than 30 microposts.

Here is the static_pages_spec.rb:

```
  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sample App') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }

    describe "for signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user) }
        sign_in user
        visit root_path
      end

      after { user.microposts.delete_all }

      it "should render the user's feed" do
        user.feed.each do |item|
          page.should have_selector("li##{item.id}", text: item.content)
        end
      end

      it "should have micropost count and pluralize" do
        page.should have_content('31 microposts')
      end

      it "should paginate after 31" do
        page.should have_selector('div.pagination')
      end
    end

  end
```

Here is my _feed_item.html.erb partial:

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with it being unable to see the next page. Because each time it comes back with a very high line item id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by limiting the feed line item test to only check the first 28 posts.

```
  it "should render the user's feed" do
    user.feed[1..28].each do |item|
      page.should have_selector("li##{item.id}", text: item.content)
    end
  end
```

However, I don't know that this is the best way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its relevant but i'll post it anyway so it might help others.

Your home page only shows 30 feed items(because of paginate) but your loop check wether all your feeds exist in your home page which they don't and that's why you've got the error...

My solution to your problem, which is similar to yours, uses paginate instead of range

```
it "should render the user's feed" do
  user.feed.paginate(page: 1).each do |item|
    page.should have_selector("li##{item.id}", text: item.content)
  end
end
```